# Why is Avogadro's law always true?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Why is [Avogadro's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro%27s_law) always true? How and why do equal volumes of gases at equal pressure and temperature contain equal number of molecules? I know it is a fundamental principle in chemistry but I wonder how it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll attempt an explanation without any equations.

In kinetic theory, the pressure exerted by an **ideal** gas (point-like, non-interacting particles, elastic collisions) depends on the rate at which momentum is exchanged with the walls of any container as the molecules bounce off them.

The momentum is of course proportional to the molecule's speed and mass, but the *rate* at which molecules hit a wall additionally depends on how fast they are going and how many molecules there are in the volume of gas.

If you put that together you find that pressure depends on the number of molecules in a volume of gas and how much *kinetic energy* each molecule has.

The final step is to understand that the (average) kinetic energy of molecules in an (ideal) gas depends only on their temperature.

Thus a gas of a given temperature and number of molecules per unit volume will always exert the same pressure (in ideal circumstances). Or to turn this around, a gas of a given pressure and temperature will contain the same number of molecules per unit volume.

If the "ideal" approximations break down, Avogadro's law may not be true.

Comment: ok that means lighter molecules travel fast but their mass is less and heavier molecules travel slow but their mass is high..so that both lighter and heavier molecules exert same average momentum change p/t (force) and hence the pressure at walls.. or pressure becomes 'mass' independent and only number dependent..

Comment: Yes, I think you have it. It ends up just depending on the kinetic energy of each particle, which does not depend on their mass, just their temperature.

Comment: I have a feeling avagadro's law should be valid only ideal gasses and certainly not for real gasses. A look at van der Waals equation shows it. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Shashaank You will find the caveat "In ideal circumstances" in my answer.

Comment: I find it helpful to pick "temperature" (among 3 parameters)  as it is easy to imagine one molecule "bringing along" a "given" temperature. However, if you pump up your bicycle what you put in is pressure, not heat, and there is a "mean free path" of a particle. I think you may pick on pressure instead of temperature (which leaves me puzzled about "volume", relating ot pressure, as  variable. (Let me share my new look gained writing: pressure can be exerted by a piston moving, this is like two particles of specific velocities hitting each other)).

Comment: @PeterBernhard yes, that sounds helpful. This is the the type of question where there isn't going to be one right answer. You should have a go at writing another one.

Comment: No need to, if everybody read the very first comment of the questioneer and your answering it: "you got it". If it were only possible and allowed, I'd integrate that point into your answer. I'd be explicit about heavier molecules being slower and hitting less often. Actually, I just set up an answer to a hiddenly related question, without consciously knowing that I got the answer from the first two comments above. - My foregoing comment still holds, though: you may "pick" any parameter, in such terms why should "it depend on" temperature alone. Great didactic approach, though, I recommend you.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's not *always* true — it's an approximation that breaks down at high pressures or at low temperatures (where many gases turn into liquids or solids). But if the mean distance between gas molecules is many, many, many times longer than the size of the molecules themselves, so that the molecules are effectively "noninteracting," then it no longer matters what species the molecules are or how they would interact if they could.

The number density of a gas at STP is approximately one [amagat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amagat), which is 45 mol/m<sup>3</sup> or $2.7\times10^{25}\,\mathrm{atoms/m^3}$. Flipping that over we find that each atom is alone in a volume of roughly 37 nm<sup>3</sup>, a cube about 3.3 nm on a side. But atoms in a solid are typically arranged in cells [about 0.3–0.5 nm on a side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_constant), and atoms in covalent bonds are typically [even closer than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_length). Imagine that I was putting on a concert you wanted to go to, and you had heard that tickets cost \$30–\$50. But when you actually got to the box office, you found out that the tickets actually cost \$300! You'd go home, no matter who you thought I was. All noninteractions are alike, so all noninteracting gases can obey the same rules.

Comment: Nice answer! Maybe a small addition that is useful for the OP. A noninteracting gas is called an *ideal gas*. That is also where the *ideal gas law* gets its name

Comment: ok. i  meant the case of ideal gases only. and my focus in the question was different molecules has different volume, but still same amount contain in same volume..

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that interstellar number densities approach $10^6$ atoms/m$^3$, nearly 20 orders of magnitude less than terrestrial gases.

Comment: Not sure how this argument holds up in the center of a star. Definitely an ideal gas, but number densities of $10^{32}$ /m$^3$. What size do we compare the particle separation to? Not atoms, because completely ionised - Wigner-Seitz sphere maybe?

Comment: @RobJeffries The difference there is temperature — the thermal collision interaction is so much stronger than the inter-atom interaction that the latter can just be neglected.

Comment: Precisely. The argument based on length scales does not seem to (straightforwardly) work for all gases. It is the KE of the particles vs the potential energy that they have at typical separations that is important.

Answer (score 2):

It holds exactly only for ideal gases, of which the constituent particles do not interact and the internal energy is merely kinetic.

Comment: +1. This is the short and sweet correct answer. Strictly speaking, Avogadro's law is **never** true. It is approximately true for some gases, most notably the noble gases. But even the noble gases exhibit non-ideal behavior to some extent.

Comment: @DavidHammen this is definitely _correct_, but not an _answer_ to the actual question, which to my understanding is asking for the underlying physical basis of Avogadro's Law. (even though the question is not strictly correct). This should be a comment on the question, not a separate answer

Comment: @VickyChijwani -- Sometimes one has to read between the lines on novice questions. "Avogadro's law is **never** true (but in some cases it is a good approximation)" is the correct answer to "Why is Avogadro's law always true?"